# How to calculate confidence level interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory

### Question:

Research is conducted which is based on poll. 2300 evenly random picked citizen are asked question which they then have to answer yes or no. Resulting in 897 "yes" answers and 1403 "no" answers. Calculate confidence level interval when confidence level is known to be 95%

### Attempt to solve:

I've tried picking distribution that would fit this but i haven't found one.

i know that for normal distribution confidence level interval can be calculated using formula

$$ m(x) \pm Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

where $m(x)$ would be estimate for $\mu$ (usually arithmetic mean will do just fine as for the estimate.) $Z$ would be value from standard normal table. For 95% confidence level we would get $Z=\pm1.96$. $\sigma$ is standard deviation and $n$ is just number of samples in this case $n=2300$

Comment: Have you learn the confidence interval for proportion?

Comment: @BGM This would be confidence interval for proportion from normal distribution ?$$ m(x)\pm Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$ I am sorry but i dont know exactly what do you mean ?.

Comment: Thats ok from your response it indicate that you have not learn that yet. Proportion here means the parameter in a Binomial distribution. Note that you have a binary outcome and the frequency of each category will follow a Binomial distribution. There are tons of website describing this CI as this is covered in most of the elementary statistic course. See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: @BGM My comment was too long so i ended up "answering" to my own question. In this example all parameters $Z$, $\hat{p}$ and $n$ are known so it would be possible to solve it like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) @BGM provided there would be few options to choose from when trying to calculate this. The most common one would be one based on observing estimate of parameter p from binomial distribution with normal distribution. Error distribution in this case wouldn't be binomial distributed it would be standard normal error instead ? Binomial distribution is defined as:
$$ Pr(K;n,p)=Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} $$

where $p$ would be probability for success in bernoulli trials. $\hat{p}$ is estimate for parameter $p$. According to [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) our $\hat{p}$ should be fairly close to the actual p. We can define normal approximation interval as:

$$ \hat{p}\pm Z \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})} $$

There are other intervals than normal approximation interval but it would be probably best to stick with this ?

### Computations:

By plugging in numbers to formula we get:

$$ \hat{p} \pm Z\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\hat{p}(1-p)} $$

$$ \frac{897}{2300} \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2300}(\frac{897}{2300})(1-(\frac{897}{2300}))} $$
$$ \approx0.39 \pm0.0199 $$

$$ lower\approx 0.37$$
$$ upper\approx 0.41$$

#### $Z$ value explained:

Z value is defined for standard normal distribution as:

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

Value of $Z$ corresponds to value on standardized normal distribution X-axis. If we take a look at standardized normal cumulative distribution function (standard normal cdf). We can determine value of $P(X\le Z)$. In this assignment we need to do this in reverse since we know probability but we don't know value for $Z$.Probability was 95% which leaves 2.5% of probability in each tail. 95% of probability is in between two standard deviations $2 \sigma$ from $\mu$ (more accurately $1.96\sigma$) and 5% would be outside of this area. We need to find corresponding $Z$ value for $P(X\le Z)=0.025$. For example you can take a look at [standard normal table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) and find out that $P(X \le -1,96)=0.025$ or alternatively  $P(X \le 1,96)=1-0.025$

---

These calculation give correct answer to the question asked. Note that this question was assignment on probability and statistics basic course (bachelor's level). I am not on expert on this subject so i cannot say if this valid on every occasion but in context of this course this applies.